# Shiny reactive expression call to local function

Tags: r, function, shiny

Using Shiny to build an app, I'm having an issue with a `reactive` call to a locally defined function.
An emulating example:

```
  <server.R>
  shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
  myfunc <- function(x) x+1
  myreac <- reactive({
          y <- myfunc(input$var)
          y
  })  
  # print y value test
  output$text <- renderText({ 
  myreac <- myreac()
  paste("This is your output:",myreac)
  })
```

Shiny UI

```
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("New App"),  
  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
  helpText("My App"),      
  selectInput("var", 
              label = "Choose an option:",
              choices = list("1", "2",
                             "3"),
              selected = "1"),
      ),

mainPanel(
  textOutput("text"),
  )   
 )
))
```

The output I am getting: is basically blank:

```
This is your output:
```

Seems like nothing is output-ed by the reactive. Any help I could get will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of extra commas, but aside from that, if you convert `x` to numeric, it should work,

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
        titlePanel("New App"),  
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                helpText("My App"),      
                selectInput("var", 
                            label = "Choose an option:",
                            choices = list("1", "2", "3"),
                            selected = "1")
            ),
            mainPanel(
                textOutput("text")
            )
        )
    )),
    shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
        myfunc <- function(x) as.numeric(x)+1
        myreac <- reactive({
            y <- myfunc(input$var)
            y
        })

        ## print y value test
        output$text <- renderText({ 
            myreac <- myreac()
            paste("This is your output:", myreac)
        })
    })
)
```

Comment: @ bunk: spot on. In original code, choices were characters and just figured there's no implicit assumption on class, so had to use `quote`. The next issue I have is that all choices are evaluated at same time...Is there a reason to that?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean.  Are you seeing output?

Comment: Yep, output prints all three choices at the same time. In example above, `This is your output: 2, This is your output: 3, This is your output: 4` despite `selectInput` being set on `1` (on user interface).

Comment: you get that when you copy and paste the above?  I'm only seeing one output at a time

Comment: Getting it on the actual code. I am using a grep in `myfunc` and it indeed complains that `pattern has length > 1...` as a warning message. It seems like all 3 "choices" get evaluated at same time?

Comment: I don't know, you arent giving me much to go on here ;p  The above works, and if your actual app is the same it should too.

Comment: @ bunk: thanks so much. Re-reading your answer, I had to coerce `as.numeric` in `myfunc` definition, rather than later during its call - argument-  inside the reactive. Resolved.